# How to set dicomfile encoding

Tags: .net-core, encoding, fo-dicom

fo-dicom 4.0.6.

netcore5

I create dicom files based on existing one. Only adding few tags in cyrillic
As I understand when I open dicomfile, tag SpecificCharacterSet is used to define tag's value encoding.
Bu as I understand I can change this behavior with custom IOManager.

F.ex. if I want force encoding 1251 I can define class

```
public class AnsiIOManager : IOManager
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    protected override Encoding BaseEncodingImpl => Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251");

    ...
}
```

And to assign this by `IOManager.SetImplementation(new AnsiIOManager());`

Am I right?

Sometimes I need to create files in different encoding at the same time in multithreading. And can I change this IOManager encoding dinamically instead of change static type value?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the default encoding in IOManager is not the right way to do that. Because you add some value to a a DicomDataset and therefore also need to update the SpeicificCharacterSet in that file. The IOManager only influences the default encoding used when parsing values.
All this encoding this have been improved dramatically in version 5.0.0. So I recommend, to use fo-dicom 5.0.0. Then you can do the following:

- load the DicomDataset
- call `dataset.AddOrUpdate(DicomTag.SpeicificCharacterSet, DicomEncoding.GetCharset( Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251") ))`, so telling the dataset, now to use the encoding you desire
- add Tags with string values

Comment: You wrote >>"The IOManager only influences the default encoding used when parsing values.Dataset". You mean parsing when getting value like GetSingleValueOrDefault(DicomTag.PatientName)?

Comment: I only can't see when IOManager  is accounted.

Comment: up until version 4 there was this IOManager. it was required, because there were various builds for various platforms (desktop, android, ios, uwp, pcl,..) and each of them had different IO methods. And yes, this encoding is just the fallback encoding when no explicit encoding can be found somewhere.

Comment: in version 5, there is only one build in netstandard2.0. this new version uses the unified .net api and therefore does not require the IOManager in that way any more.